# An estimation of $\frac{dy}{dt} \le gy+h$.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, inequality

Question: Let $g,h,y$ be positive locally integrable functions on $(t_o,+\infty)$ such that $y'$ is locally integrable on $(t_0,+\infty$) and for all $t \le t_0$ the following inequalities are satisfied:

$\frac{dy}{dt} \le gy+h$; $\int_t^{t+r}g(s)ds \le a_1$; $\int_t^{t+r}h(s)ds \le a_2$; $\int_t^{t+r}y(s)ds \le a_3$,

where $r,a_1,a_2,a_3$ are positive constants. Prove that $y(t+r) \le (\frac{a_3}{r}+a_2)e^{a_1}$.

My attempt:

I found $y(t+r)e^{\int_t^{t+r}-g(\tau)d\tau} \le \int_t^{t+r}e^{\int_t^{s}-g(\tau)d\tau}h(s)ds+y(t)$ by mutliplying $e^{\int_t^{s}-g(\tau)d\tau}$ and integrating with respect to $s$ form $t$ to $t+r$ on the both sides of $y'(s)-g(s)y(s)\le h(s)$ .

Use the inqualities above, I got $y(t+r) \le (y(t)+a_2) e^{a_1}$. However, I don't know how to use the last inequality and get the final estimation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the question by myself. Here is my final proof:

Actually, for all $\rho \le r$, I have the estimation: $y(t+\rho) \le (y(t)+a_2)e^{a_1}$ (just by integrating with respect to $s$ from $t$ to $t+\rho$ rather than $t+r$ in the previous attempt). In another word, $y(t') \le (y(t'-\rho)+a_2)e^{a_1}$, here $t'$ can be any number no less than $t_0+r$ such that $y(t'-\rho)$ makes sense for all $\rho \le r$. Integrate on the both sides with respect to $\rho$ from $0$ to $r$, $ry(t') \le e^{a_1}\int_0^r(y(t'-\rho)+a_2)d\rho \le e^{a_1}(a_3+a_2r)$, i.e. $y(t') \le e^{a_1}(\frac{a_3}{r}+a_2)$.

Hence, $y(t+r) \le e^{a_1}(\frac{a_3}{r}+a_2)\quad (\forall t \ge t_0)$.